# Cayley-Hamilton Theorem: characteristic polynomial and distinct eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

I do not know where to start for solving this exercise although I have the "official" solution. In the solution, I see that some variables are exchanged but I cannot connect the steps to a coherent "story". Some direct help is highly appreciated. I do know how to get the poles from a characteristic equation.

**Exercise**

Consider a matrix $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ with the characteristic polynomial
$$ \det(sI-A)=a(s)=s^n+a_{n-1}s^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_1 s+a_0 $$

a) Show that if $ A $ has distinct eigenvalues $(λ_1, λ_2, \ldots , λ_n)$, the following relationship holds:
$$ \Lambda^n + a_{n-1}\Lambda^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_0 I = 0 $$
with $ \Lambda =  \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda_n
        \end{pmatrix}  $

b) Now show that 
$$ A^n + a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_0 I = 0  $$

(This proves the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem for distinct eigenvalues.)
*Hint: Use the fact that a matrix A with distinct eigenvalues can be written as
$A = T ΛT^{−1}$; where $Λ$ is diagonal.*

**Solution**:

a) The characteristic equation is true for all eigenvalues of $A$, $λ_1 . . . λ_n$
$$ \lambda^n + a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots + a_0  = 0 $$
$$ \Lambda = \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda_n
        \end{pmatrix}  $$
so $ \Lambda^n + a_{n-1} \Lambda^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_0 I = 0 $

This is the matrix characteristic equation.

b) With distinct eigenvalues and diagonal $Λ$ we have
$$ A=T\Lambda T^{-1} \\ A^2 = T \Lambda T^{-1} T \Lambda T^{-1} = T \Lambda^2 T^{-1} \\ \vdots \\ A^m=T \Lambda^m T^{-1}$$

Multiply the matrix characteristic equation by $T$ (left) and $T^{-1}$ (right) to obtain $$T \Lambda^n T^{-1} + a_{n-1}T \Lambda^{n-1} T^{-1}+\cdots + a_0 TT^{-1}= 0 $$
$$ A^n + a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0 I = 0 $$

Comment: You do not get the roots from the characteristic equation (in most cases you can't), then were given to you by the authors of this exercise.

Comment: Why can I not get roots from a characteristic equation? Usually, the ABC formula will help me to get the roots. In case of higher orders of polynomials, Matlab could help me. I am really puzzled what I am supposed to learn from this exercise.

Comment: in general case for a matrix of dimension $5$ the eigenvalues are not expressible in radicals. A couple of decades ago Godunov and his students made a $7\times 7$ matrix with small int eger entries (around $10^4..10^5$) with eigenvalues $0,\pm 1,\pm2,\pm 4$. None of the existing software back then could find those eigenvalues - Mathematica, Maple, Matlab, Reduce, you name it. Whatever the numerical method there will always be matrix that beats that method.

Comment: What about brute forcing? :-)

Comment: good luck with that=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you are done. Let
$ \det(sI-A)=a(s)=s^n+a_{n-1}s^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_1 s+a_0 $ be the characteristic polynomial. We know by assumption that it has exactly $n$ distinct roots, namely: $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$.

Let $ \Lambda =  \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_2 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda_n
        \end{pmatrix}\text{  }$ be the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the roots of $a(s)$.

We want to show that $ \Lambda^n + a_{n-1}\Lambda^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_0 I = 0. $ Since

$$\Lambda^k =  \begin{pmatrix}
        \lambda_1^k & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & \lambda_2^k & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda_n^k
        \end{pmatrix},$$

thus  $$\Lambda^n + a_{n-1}\Lambda^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_0 I=
\begin{pmatrix}
        a(\lambda_1) & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & a(\lambda_2) & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & 0 & a(\lambda_n)
        \end{pmatrix}=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        0 & \cdots & 0 & 0
        \end{pmatrix}$$
because $\lambda_i$ are roots of $a(s)$.

The second part asks to prove the theorem for a matrix $A$ similar to $\Lambda$, *i.e.*

$$ A^n + a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+ \cdots + a_0 I = 0 .$$

Thus $A = T ΛT^{−1}$; where $Λ$ is diagonal, by definition of similarity; and

$$ A^k = T\Lambda^k T^{-1} \quad \forall k\in \Bbb N.$$

Finally: $$A^n + a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0 I = 0\Longleftrightarrow T \Lambda^n T^{-1} + a_{n-1}T \Lambda^{n-1} T^{-1}+\cdots + a_0 TT^{-1}= 0 $$
$$\Longleftrightarrow T( \Lambda^n + a_{n-1} \Lambda^{n-1} +\cdots + a_0I)T^{-1}= 0 \Longleftrightarrow \Lambda^n + a_{n-1} \Lambda^{n-1} +\cdots + a_0I =T^{-1}0T=0.$$

Comment: and what do I know now with this result? In other words, if the eigenvalues are in diagonal form in a matrix, the result of the polynomial function is zero, correct? Why do we have to write the $T$ and $T^{-1}$ in $A^k = T \Lambda^kT^{-1} $, if $ A = \Lambda^k $ anyway?

Comment: If $A=\Lambda$ then $T=I$, but in general there many matrices having the same characteristic polynomial, and only one of these is diagonal. Precisely: if two matrices $A,B$ are similar i.e. $A=TBT^{-1}$ for some $T$, then they have the same characteristic polynomial. So the second part asks you to prove that: if $\Lambda$ is a solution of $a(s)$, then also every similar matrices are solutions.